# Trouble Connecting with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

To be completely up front, I am a novice when it comes to a lot of database-related topics.  I am a data scientist, but my background lends itself more to statistical modeling.  So please be patient with me :)

I am trying to use a query service of Adobe Experience Platform (AEP) which relies on PostgreSQL.  For the life of me, I can not get it working.  I've tried lots of things and I get the following:

> Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly  This probably means
>   the server terminated abnormally  before or while processing the
>   request.

Can anyone help me determine the root cause of the issue?

Comment: can you add some database's log?

Comment: host = "aresprodvalidation.platform-query.adobe.io"
port = 80

Does that give you enough information to work with without giving you the username and password?

Comment: That doesn't log like the databases log, but more like some middleware log.  The database shouldn't be running on port 80.  Is the database log reporting that the client disappeared unexpectedly?  Or that the database itself crashed?

Comment: What tool are you attempting to connect with (e.g. psql, RStudio etc...)? Perhaps start with psql ([adobe docs](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experienceplatform/home/query-service/connect.html#!api-specification/markdown/narrative/technical_overview/query-service/clients/psql.md)).

Comment: @Brits -- I was originally attempting to connect via RStudio, but when I was unsuccessful, I tried just doing some initial troubleshooting in the terminal and got the exact same error message.

Comment: OK - Are you using the PSQL command provided by the ["Connect BI Tools"](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experienceplatform/home/query-service/connect.html#!api-specification/markdown/narrative/technical_overview/query-service/clients/psql.md) page? Can you please also provide a bit more info; e.g. is the connection established at all? if established how long is it up before you get the error etc. There are many potential causes here but currently there is not enough info to provide much assistance.

Comment: @Brits -- Thanks for the response.

I've followed the connections on that link a few times and the result is always the same:

"psql: error: could not connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request."

It looks to me like a connection is never established as the error is pretty much immediate.

Comment: @JessicaLangford Sorry but I'd say your best bet is to raise a a support issue with Adobe. There is a chance that the issue is due to something to do with your computer/internet link but it's just as possible that the problem is on the Adobe side. If you want to rule out things on your side then try accessing the system from another computer using a different internet link.